# Google Analytics Handling multiple domains

Tags: web, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Hello There I have 3 different sites hosted on same server having different domains. Let's say they are

```
www.abc.com
www.xyz.com
www.mno.com
```

I have successfully integrated google tracking code (using ga.js) and get data through reporting api for `www.abc.com`. Now I also want tracking of data and getting data for others too. What I need to do that? Can I create seperate profiles in same google account for all three sites? Or I need to create separate google analytics account for each site or I can do it with same profile and same account?

I have searched but couldn't be able to find out any solutions. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GA is structured in an Account --> Property --> Profile way.

So for your example I would suggest the best method would be to run all the sites in the same account, but create a new Property for each site.

When you do this GA will give you a new UA-xxxxxx-x number for each site.

Check this out for more help https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042508?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=1009620

Cheers

John